# Why do the Ricci and scalar curvature of an Einstein metric have the same sign?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the picture below, seemly, if the scalar curvature is positive , then ,the Ricci tensor is positive , because I can use norm coordinate make the $g_{ij}\ge 0$.

As I know ,$R=g^{ij}R_{ij}$ , I think the positive of $R$ can't make $R_{ij}$ is positive . Why the paper is not so ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're asking? My best guesses are: 1. "Why do the Ricci and scalar curvature of an Einstein metric have the same sign?" and 2. Why does an Einstein metric evolve by homothety under Ricci flow?", but I have a suspicion neither guess is correct.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  First is correct. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize your English, just wanted not to give a mis-directed response. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Thanks your help. I will correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is an Einstein metric on a smooth $n$-manifold, and if $R_{ij} = \lambda g_{ij}$ for some real $\lambda$, then
$$
R = g^{ij} R_{ij} = n\lambda,
$$
which has the same sign as $\lambda$.